# jQuery to run on Appended Loaded HTML

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a chrome extension to append a custom html menu to a page by using Content Script. The content works just fine and menu works perfectly, but I'm currently loading the HTML from within a var, like this:

```
var gacMenu = '';
    gacMenu+='<div id="menu">';
    gacMenu+='menu content HTML';
    gacMenu+='menu content HTML';
    gacMenu+='menu content HTML';
    gacMenu+='menu content HTML';
    gacMenu+='</div>';
```

and then append to the page like this:

```
$("body").append(gacMenu);
```

Since I'm still creating the menu itself, editing the HTML from the var is kind of annoying, and I was trying to create a separated HTML with just the menu code and then LOAD and APPEND this file to the page by using this code:

```
$(function() {
  $('body').append($('body').load('menu.html'));
});
```

The content is loaded but the problem is that other jquery functions like .click() and .change() doesn't work with the Loaded & Appended content, only when it's loaded from the var.

On the working scenario, both var with HTML and jquery functions are in the same JS file. Here is some code that works when HTML is loaded from var, but that doesn't work when HTML is loaded from file:

```
$("input:checkbox[name=onoffswitch]").change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      chrome.storage.sync.set({'gacMenuSwitch': '1'}, function(toggleOn){ // Define a variável condificonal do menu para 1
        console.log('Switch is ON' + '\n' + 'Menu var is set to 1');
      });
  } else {
      chrome.storage.sync.set({'gacMenuSwitch': '0'}, function(toggleOff){ // Define a variável condificonal do menu para 0
        console.log('Switch is OFF' + '\n' + 'Menu var is set to 0');
      });
    } // fim do if/else
});
```

I'm sorry if this is a lame question, but I'm on early stages of programming. What I'm missing?

Comment: Thanks for pointing. I've edited my question. Everything is in the same .js file called menu.js, but when a try to append the HTML from menu.html, the code from menu.js doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I think it's because `load` is asynchronous, so you should put that code into a function for `complete` parameter: `load('menu.html', function() { /* attach event handlers */ });`

Comment: Actually I was wrong. It seems that the .load() doesn't get the content from the HTML. When I try to alert() the load, it just show [object] [object] when I guess it should show the HTML content, right?

Comment: Yeah, you should list `load.html` in [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources).

Comment: I've defined the manifest with `"web_accessible_resources": ["menu.html"],` but still, when I use `$.get("menu.html", function(response) {var logfile = response; alert(response);});` from menu.js to test it out, the alert shows only **[object] [object]** :(

Comment: Please read the documentation completely: `These resources would then be available in a webpage via the URL chrome-extension://[PACKAGE ID]/[PATH], which can be generated with the extension.getURL method. ` or google for answers, it shouldn't take more than a couple of minutes.

Comment: Alright so, menu.html is now whitelisted on `web_accessible_resources"` and alert response was able to find the HTML using `chrome.extension.getURL('menu.html')`. I've now appended the HTML using `$.get(chrome.extension.getURL('menu.html'), function(data2) {$(data2).appendTo('body');});` and included all jquery inside the get callback, and everything seems to be working now. thank you, thank you so much :D

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @wOxxOm I find out there were a few things to do in order to append the HTML using Content Scripts.

1. I had to whitelist my file "menu.html" on the manifest by using `"web_accessible_resources": ["menu.html"]`
2. I created a get() with an alert before the actual append just to see if the HTML was being pulled. I had some issues because i was not using the chrome.extension.getURL to search for the file and the get() was returnin **[object] [object]** instead of HTML, so once I did `chrome.extension.getURL('menu.html')` everything was fine
3. I was having trouble with the previous .append() and .load() I've posted, so I tried using `$.get(chrome.extension.getURL('menu.html'), function(data2) {$(data2).appendTo('body');});` and was able to grab the file. All jquery that was not working were moved to inside the callback of the get, so everything is right now